# How to have custom font styling in markdown files ( .md files)?

Tags: css, fonts, markdown

I have a few markdown files in my recat webiste. I want to style that page with custom fonts from .css file , how can i do it?

Comment: https://mdxjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on the markdown engine you're using, but you can almost always use HTML tags and therefore styling in your markdown files. It's usually easier and more compatible to have in-line styles in your tags. Suppose you want a purple text area with underline and borders, you can achieve that with:

```markdown
<p style="color: pink; background-color: #1f1f1f;font-size: large; padding: 15px; border-radius: 20px; border: 1px solid pink;">
    Hello world
</p>
```

> Just keep in mind that certain services such as GitHub will override your styles, but it does work for standalone uses.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by including link to to css file below header

```
---
title: Section 1
---
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="URL" />
```

or by using the import statement and then using the class defined in that css file

```
---
title: Section 1
---
 import styles from 'path name'
    
 <div className={}>

  markdown file contents

  </div>
```